# Test for clustered data, multinomial response, ordinal categorical variables, unbalanced design

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, ordinal-data, unbalanced-classes

I have a data set consisting of samples of contaminated water collected at different times at different sites. Each sample has an associated contamination level (`<lod`, `low`, `medium`, `high`). So, my data looks as follows:

```
site   date        sample_number water_temperature contamination
----   ----------  ------------- ----------------- -------------
  S1   2015-01-01              1               hot        medium
  S1   2015-01-01              2              cold           low
  S1   2015-01-01              3               hot           low
  S1   2015-06-12              1               hot          high
  S2   2015-06-24              1               hot          <lod
  S2   2015-06-24              2              cold          <lod
 ...          ...            ...               ...           ...
```

There a few hundred sites in the data set. Sites have been inspected a variable number of times (some sites have been surveyed just once, while some other sites maybe have been surveyed a few hundred times) during a decade. For each survey, a variable amount of (hot and/or cold water) samples has been collected (for some surveys, there is just one sample, while for other surveys more than thirty). Moreover, there are much more hot water samples than cold water samples.

The question is whether hot water has significantly higher levels of contamination than cold water. Cross-tabulated data looks as follows:

```
     <lod  low medium high
cold  537   59     33    6
hot  8994  798    723  199
```

Which methods can be used to tackle this problem? I was thinking to use some variant of permutation tests, but it is not clear to me which permutation strategy I might use. Maybe something more sophisticated like GEEs can accommodate for these data?